# Error CS0118 'TestBuilder' is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing, testing

I'm working on Unit test. I create TestBuilder class, where I create method SetupTown method.
When I tried call this method in my main test class - i have error( Error CS0118'TestBuilder' is a namespace but is used like a type). I read about it and recommend to call a class with method. I tried do it, but It doesn't help.

**public partial class TownServiceTests**

```
 public partial class TownServiceTests
    {
        private class TestBuilder
        {
            public Mock<ITownRepository> MockTownRepository { get; set; }

            //public Mock<IClientViewModelBuilder> MockClientPropertyModelBuilder { get; set; }

            public Mock<IMapper> MockMapper { get; set; }

            public TestDataGenerator TestDataGenerator;

            private readonly string _jsonDataPath = @"../../../TestData/Town/TownTestData.json";

            private string _jsonDataKey;

            private TownViewModel Towns { get; set; }

            public TestBuilder(string jsonDataKey)
            {
                MockTownRepository = new Mock<ITownRepository>();

                //MockClientPropertyModelBuilder = new Mock<IClientViewModelBuilder>();

                MockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

                TestDataGenerator = new TestDataGenerator(_jsonDataPath);

                _jsonDataKey = jsonDataKey;

                TestDataGenerator.LoadData(_jsonDataKey);
            }

            public ITownService Build()
            {
                return new TownService(MockTownRepository.Object,
                                        MockMapper.Object);
            }

            public TestBuilder SetupTowns()
            {
                var towns = TestDataGenerator.GetTestData<Town>(_jsonDataKey, "Towns");

                MockTownRepository.Setup(r => r.InsertTown(It.IsAny<string>()))    
                                    .ReturnsAsync(towns.FirstOrDefault().Id);               

                return this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please check method **public TestBuilder SetupTowns**

Here my **TestClass**

```
    [TestClass]
    public partial class TownServiceTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task ValidInsertTown()
        {
            var builder = new TestBuilder("Data").SetupTowns; //Problem

            var service = builder.Build();

            var expectedTowns = builder.TestDataGenerator.GetTestData<Town>("Data", "Towns");

            var result = await service.InsertTown(expectedTowns);

            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.IsNull(result);
        }
    }
```

Could toy tell me what I do wrong?

**Example**

```
 public partial class ClientServiceTests
    {
        private class TestBuilder
        {
            public Mock<IClientRepository> MockClientRepository { get; set; }

            public Mock<IClientViewModelBuilder> MockClientPropertyModelBuilder { get; set; }

            public Mock<IMapper> MockMapper { get; set; }

            public TestDataGenerator TestDataGenerator;

            private readonly string _jsonDataPath = @"../../../TestData/Client/ClientTestData.json";

            private string _jsonDataKey;

            public TestBuilder(string jsonDataKey)
            {
                MockClientRepository = new Mock<IClientRepository>();

                MockClientPropertyModelBuilder = new Mock<IClientViewModelBuilder>();

                MockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

                TestDataGenerator = new TestDataGenerator(_jsonDataPath);

                _jsonDataKey = jsonDataKey;

                TestDataGenerator.LoadData(_jsonDataKey);
            }

            public IClientService Build()
            {
                return new ClientService(MockClientRepository.Object
                                       , MockClientPropertyModelBuilder.Object
                                       , MockMapper.Object);
            }

            public TestBuilder SetupClients()
            {
                var clients = TestDataGenerator.GetTestData<ClientSummary>(_jsonDataKey, "Clients");

                MockClientRepository.Setup(r => r.GetClientBySearchCriteria(It.IsAny<string>()))
                                    .ReturnsAsync(clients);

                var clientViewModels = TestDataGenerator.GetTestData<ClientViewModel>(_jsonDataKey, "ClientViewModel");

                MockClientPropertyModelBuilder.Setup(r => r.GetClientViewModel(clients))
                                              .Returns(clientViewModels);

                return this;
            }

            public TestBuilder SetupInvalidInputClients()
            {
                MockClientRepository.Setup(r => r.GetClientBySearchCriteria(It.IsAny<string>()))
                                    .ReturnsAsync(new List<ClientSummary>());

                MockClientPropertyModelBuilder.Setup(r => r.GetClientViewModel(new List<ClientSummary>()))
                                              .Returns(new List<ClientViewModel>());

                return this;
            }
        }
    }
```

**TestClass** (here works good)

```
 [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetClientBySearchCriteria_ValidInput_ReturnClients()
        {
            var searchParameter = "1";

            var builder = new TestBuilder("Data").SetupClients();

            var service = builder.Build();

            var expectedClients = builder.TestDataGenerator.GetTestData<ClientSummary>("Data", "Clients");

            var result = await service.GetClientBySearchCriteria(searchParameter);

            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedClients.FirstOrDefault().Name, result.FirstOrDefault().Name);
        }
```

**namespace of the file**
[image]

Comment: `var builder = new TownServiceTests.TestBuilder("Data").SetupTowns;`

Comment: It doesn't work "Error CS0426 The type name 'TestBuilder' does not exist in the type 'TownServiceTests' "

Comment: The compiler doesn't tend to lie. Is it possible you also have used `TestBuilder` as a namespace name somewhere? If so, it seems like name lookup is finding that before the class you were hoping it would find. It also seems likely that the namespace declarations are different between the two files, meaning that what you're presenting as two partials of a single class are in fact not, because they're in different namespaces. Unfortunately, you're not showing us the namespaces of the files.

Comment: I'm added a screen of my namespace of the files

Comment: That shows us the filesystem layout, effectively. It tells us nothing about the `namespace X.Y.Z` lines at the top of the individual files.

Comment: @КириллФилободченко its my bad.... it should be `var builder = new ClientServiceTests.TestBuilder("Data").SetupTowns;` coz TestBuilder class is inside `ClientServiceTests` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the issue is happened because you have Something.TestBuilder.Something namespace and compiler is trying to use it instead of class.

You have the TestBuilder folder and a few classes inside it. It may be that classes inside TestBuilder folder contains `TestBuilder` in their namespaces and compiler trying to access this namespace instead of class.

Comment: Are you sure? I added **example**, it works good with the same situation

Comment: i noticed it only now, but are you trying to call SetupTowns method without parentheses?
`new TestBuilder("Data").SetupTowns` instead of `new TestBuilder("Data").SetupTowns()`

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I fix it. But situation doesn't change

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, so i think that the problem is somewhere else, e.g. you created namespace called TestBuilder

Comment: I added screen of my namespace

Comment: The TownServiceTests.TestBuilder.cs file is located inside TestBuilder folder. It is possible that partial class TownServiceTests inside this folder has different namespace so it is interpreted as different classes.

Comment: Yeah, true. Do you think that this is a problem? 
Why does then in **example** all works good? Because the same situation